# Arquillian with weblogic 10.3

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, weblogic-10.x, jboss-arquillian

Our project has started mandating us to write tests for all modules going into Prod from now on. We have cases where a Spring POJO has some injected EJBs and these EJBs are used within the POJO methods. Since we couldn't find a way to unit test injected EJBs within a POJO (tried various ways but were unsuccessful), we were suggested to use Arquillian. I configured Arquillian to run on a local JBoss 6.0.0 server - all their tests ran properly from command line as well as from Eclipse.

However, our test and prod environments use Weblogic 10.3 server. I havent found much information as to how we could configure Arquillian unit tests to run in weblogic. If anyone has tried this earlier, could you please let me know which config files and what to change ?

-Sonu

Answer (score 1):

The properties to be specified in the `arquillian.xml` file for WLS 10.3, are listed in the [Arquillian Reference Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/WLS+10.3+-+Remote). Usually, one may need to specify the mandatory properties, but should the need arise, other properties can be specified as well.

Note that, the contents of this page are for the 1.0.0.Alpha1 version at the moment, and would be revised at some point in the future in subsequent releases (when they are made).

Comment: Thanks a lot Vineet - this product has such little information with regards to weblogic. After making the changes in arquillian.xml under arquillian-container-wls\wls-remote-10.3\src\test\resources folder, how do we go about executing maven tests ? With JBoss, I ran    'mvn install' and 'mvn test -Pjbossas-remote6'.

Also, when you mean Alpha1 version, does this mean that this product is not yet fully ready to work with Weblogic ?

Comment: Hi Vineet, one more question for you - do you know if this arquillian connector for weblogic works fine with Weblogic 10.3.1.0 server ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Sonu, `mvn test -Pjbossas-remote6` would work, if you've created a profile in your POM containing the Arquillian dependencies, including the `arquillian-wls-remote-10.3` dependency. See [these](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Setting+up+and+running+the+test+in+Maven) [pages](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Supported+containers). AFAIK, the Arquillian integration for WLS would work on 10.3.1 given the similarities with 10.3.3 and 10.3.5 which were used for testing, but I haven't verified this.

Comment: thanks again. I tried doing that earlier in the day. After modifying arquillian.xml to reflect my wls server parameters, I added a new profile  for wls but when I run the test, I get an error that says:
_italic_<error message="Arquillian has previously been attempted initialized, but failed. See previous exceptions for cause."_italic_

Comment: I did a copy paste of the profile for jbosssas-remote-6 in the pom.xml and created a new one below for weblogic-remote-10-3 with the same dependencies but I get the error as reflected in my above post when I run the unit tests. Any idea what I might be doing wrong ? Thanks a lot man - at this point, you are my only hope. - Sonu.

Comment: I missed your point about the weblogic remote being at 1.0.0.Alpha1 version but my Arquillian version is 1.0.0.Alpha5. Does this mean that these two are incompatible ? If so, would I have to download Arquillian 1.0.0.Alpha1 version to test it on weblogic ?

Comment: @Sonu, You can specify the Arquillian version as 1.0.0.CR7 and the WLS-remote version as 1.0.0.Alpha1.

Comment: After modifying arquillian.xml to reflect my wls server parameters, I added a new profile for wls but when I run the test, I get an error that says: **_<error message="Arquillian has previously been attempted initialized, but failed. See previous exceptions for cause."_**. Would you know what causes this error ?

Comment: @Sonu, that usually means that a failure in a previous test was detected. You'll need to take a look at all the SureFire logs for the test run in the target. Perhaps, it would be a better idea to post the stacktrace and further questions at the Jboss forum for Arquillian.

Comment: I posted the same question on Jboss forum for Arquillian as well but had no responses there. Anyways, thank you for the help so far though. I will try to check the Surefire logs.